# netbeans indenting blank lines by 1 space (ht undo?)

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm writing Java in NB 8.2 and a bit out of the blue, it started indenting blank lines by 1 space.  All the indenting inside of code blocks is still picture perfect.  But completely outside of any code or class, and outside of any comment blocks, if I hit enter, I get a new line, and a space.  Yuck.  Any way to kill this off? (and just get the new line, with no space)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Comical, but painful: a space got itself inserted at the very top of the file (i.e., right before the 'p' in the word "package").

So NetBeans ... was just following my lead. ;)